# Rails open_uri and amazon s3 `open_http': 403 Forbidden (OpenURI::HTTPError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, open-uri

I am trying to parse a pdf file stored remotely on s3. This is the code I have when I parse the file on my local drive

```
@doc = current_user.docs.order("created_at").last #last file uploaded by user
io = open("#{Rails.root}/public" + @doc.doc.url)
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
```

I have no issue to obtain the url of the file on s3 using this code

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
access_key_id: 'XXX',
secret_access_key: 'XXX',
region: 'eu-west-1')
bucket = s3.bucket('my_bucket')
object = bucket.object('mydoc.pdf')
puts object.public_url
```

However, when I try to open this url as follows

```
io = open(object.public_url)
```

I also tried with string interpolation

```
io = open("#{object.public_url}")
```

I get the error `open_http': 403 Forbidden (OpenURI::HTTPError)

How can I get around that? What is the right way to open a URL of a file stored on s3? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
io = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(object.public_url))
```

Comment: Thanks. This does not trigger error but does not do the job for the next step with the pdf-reader gem (reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)) which gives me the error `extract_io_from': input must be an IO-like object or a filename (ArgumentError)

Comment: try `open(Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(object.public_url)))`